# Word to indicate something drawn whence many sources

Tags: single-word-requests

As per the title, I am looking for a word (adjective I believe) that describes: 
 "something which has been inspired by many sources"; "is a collection of things from a variety of sources". It is on the tip of my tongue, yet I can't remember it and it is going to drive me insane. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the causal link between "something drawn" and "many sources" in your title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest **Eclectic**

Mirriam-Webster gives the following definition:

> 1: selecting what appears to be best in various doctrines, methods, or styles
>
> 2: composed of elements drawn from various sources

Comment: ¶Thank you! That is exactly the word! I knew I would know it when I saw it and there it is! Thank you very much for your assistance kind sir.